# Can I add a wait step after journey and then add a query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, sfmc-einstein, sfmcadmin

I have a question - I run an automation with 3 queries and a journey. The 3rd query is suppose to run after the journey, as this is the reporting query that logs users who entered the journey. Is it a good option to add a wait step of 2-hours until users exit the journey and add my last query after journey step?

OR it is better to use another automation for the 3rd query? Let me know. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't tell how you write the SQL query for the track log, I assume that the last query is getting journey data source DE to the log DE, like normally I would do.

In this case, you don't actually need to add the wait step since it already injected all contacts from the data source into the journey at the time step 3 finished.

I don't see any problems with using a separate automation for the logging query, but I would put it in the current automation so I can easily understand and maintain it.